# python BeautifulSoup find all input for specific form

Tags: python, html, forms, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to use `BeautifulSoup` to extract input fields for a specific form only.

Extracting the form using the following:

```
soup.find('form')
```

Now I want to extract all input fields which are a child to that form only.

How can I do that with BS?

Comment: `inputs = soup.find('form').find_all('input')` it should do the trick

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted in comments, *chain `find` and `find_all()`* for the context-specific search:

```
form = soup.find('form')
inputs = form.find_all('input')
```

If you want direct `input` elements only, add [`recursive=False`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument):

```
form.find_all('input', recursive=False)
```

Or, using [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select("form input")
```

And, getting direct `input` child elements only:

```
soup.select("form > input")
```

Comment: Note that there are more form element than just `input` that you might care about, including `button`, `select`, and `textarea`. https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html

Comment: I assumed that all elements in the form would have a "name=" attribute: `form = soup.select_one('form#form_id'); fields = form.select('[name]')`